# Can a finally block know if there was an exception

Tags: python, exception, try-finally

In a Python program I have code with the following structure:

```python
try:
    value = my_function(*args)
finally:
    with some_context_manager:
        do_something()
        if 'value' in locals():
            do_something_else(value)
```

But the `'value' in locals()` construction feels a bit fragile and I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

What I really want is for the code inside the `finally` to behave slightly different depending on whether the `try` block raised an exception. Is there a way to know if an exception was raised?

Comment: I think what you want is another context manager, not the try/finally syntax. `__exit__` will know if there was an exception.

Comment: You could also use the `else` block, it runs only when when no exception was raised.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary The `else` block will run before the `finally` block, which changes the semantic of OP's code.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary But the code I only want to run when there was no exception is inside a context manager invoked by the `finally` block.

Comment: Does `do_something` absolutely have to run *after* `my_function`?

Comment: @chepner Yes. `do_something` must run inside the the context manager and only after `my_function` has returned. The order of `do_something` and `do_something_else` is interchangeable.

Answer (score 3):

If the goal is "when an exception was raised, do something different", how about:

```
exception_raised = False
try:
    value = my_function(*args)
except:
    exception_raised = True
    raise
finally:
    with some_context_manager:
        do_something()
        if not exception_raised:
            do_something_else(value)
```

Now, if you're going to have multiple exceptions that you actually do something with, I'd recommend:

```
completed_successfully = False
try:
    value = my_function(*args)
else:
    completed_successfully = True
finally:
    with some_context_manager:
        do_something()
        if completed_sucessfully:
            do_something_else(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple ideas:

Set value before attempting the try:

```
value = None
try:
    value = my_function(*args)
finally:
    with some_context_manager:
        do_something()
        if value is not None:
            do_something_else(value)
```

Or if you want to set the value based on the exception type:

```
try:
    value = my_function(*args)
except:
    value = None
    raise
finally:
    with some_context_manager:
        do_something()
        if value is not None:
            do_something_else(value)
```

Comment: You assume `my_function` will never return `None`, which makes your solution a bit less general than the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43308834/3476849) by [mwchase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2117569/mwchase). But yours is slightly shorter, so I'll probably end up using it anyway, since `my_function` happens to only return strings. (I will remove the `'` chars though).

Answer (score -1):

Assign the exception to a variable in the except suite then use it in the finally suite.

```
foo = False
try:
    raise KeyError('foo not found')
except KeyError as e:
    pprint(e)
    foo = e
finally:
    if foo:
        print(foo)
    else:
        print('NO')
```

Comment: Your code will raise a `NameError` if there was no `KeyError`.

Comment: Now `foo` will not be initialized if an exception which is not a `KeyError` occurs before the final line of the `try` block..

Comment: Rats... is this even viable?  Will ```foo``` be in scope *inside* a context manager in the finally suite?

Comment: well you could initialize it outside of the `try` block.